# Vault Helm Chart not using Config from values.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, vault, argo

I'm trying to install Hashicorp Vault with the official Helm chart from Hashicorp. I'm installing it via Argocd via the UI. I have a git repo with values.yaml file that specifies some config thats not default (for example, ha mode and AWS KMS unseal). When I set up the chart via the Argocd web UI, I can point it to the values.yaml file, and see the values I set in the `parameters` section of the app. However, when I deploy the chart, the config doesn't get applied. I checked the configmap created by the chart, and it seems to follow the defaults despite my overrides. I'm thinking perhaps I'm using argocd wrong as I'm fairly new to it, although it very clearly shows the overrides from my values.yaml in the app's parameters.

Here is the relevant section of my values.yaml

```
server:
  extraSecretEnvironmentVars: 
    - envName: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
      secretName: vault
      secretKey: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    - envName: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
      secretName: vault
      secretKey: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    - envName: AWS_KMS_KEY_ID
      secretName: vault
      secretKey: AWS_KMS_KEY_ID   
  ha:
    enabled: true
    replicas: 3
    apiAddr: https://myvault.com:8200
    clusterAddr: https://myvault.com:8201

    raft:
      enabled: true
      setNodeId: false
  config: |
    ui = true
    listener "tcp" {
      tls_disable = 1
      address = "[::]:8200"
      cluster_address = "[::]:8201"
    }
    storage "raft" {
      path = "/vault/data"
    }
    service_registration "kubernetes" {}
    seal "awskms" {
      region = "us-west-2"
      kms_key_id = "$VAULT_KMS_KEY_ID"
    }
```

However, the deployed config looks like this

```
    disable_mlock = true
    ui = true

    listener "tcp" {
      tls_disable = 1
      address = "[::]:8200"
      cluster_address = "[::]:8201"
      # Enable unauthenticated metrics access (necessary for Prometheus Operator)
      #telemetry {
      #  unauthenticated_metrics_access = "true"
      #}
    }
    storage "file" {
      path = "/vault/data"
    }

    # Example configuration for using auto-unseal, using Google Cloud KMS. The
    # GKMS keys must already exist, and the cluster must have a service account
    # that is authorized to access GCP KMS.
    #seal "gcpckms" {
    #   project     = "vault-helm-dev"
    #   region      = "global"
    #   key_ring    = "vault-helm-unseal-kr"
    #   crypto_key  = "vault-helm-unseal-key"
    #}

    # Example configuration for enabling Prometheus metrics in your config.
    #telemetry {
    #  prometheus_retention_time = "30s",
    #  disable_hostname = true
    #}
```

I've tried several changes to this config, such as setting the `AWS_KMS_UNSEAL` environment variable, which doesnt seem to get applied. I've also execed into the containers and none of my environment variables seem to be set when I run a `printenv` command. I can't seem to figure out why its deploying the pods with the default config.

Comment: If you haven't already, please first check with `helm template --debug -f <your_values.yaml> <name> <chart>` and look at the output if your values get picked up. If not, it may be that your values file is not properly formatted (e.g. variable names/paths don't match expected values). You can also do a more comprehensive check with `helm install --dry-run --debug -f <your_values.yaml> <name> <chart>` to simulate a complete install. I hope they give a hint..

Comment: This got me on the right path, I ran this and indeed was not seeing the config I had applied. Not entirely sure where my formatting was off, but I then went with a much more stripped down config from the Vault documentation [here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/platform/k8s/helm), and it seems to be working  now. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! This is a great troubleshooting tool

Answer (score 0):

With the help of murtiko I figured this out. My indentation of the `config` block was off. It needs to be nested below the `ha` block. My working config looks like this:

```
global:
  enabled: true
server:
  extraSecretEnvironmentVars:
    - envName: AWS_REGION
      secretName: vault
      secretKey: AWS_REGION
    - envName: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
      secretName: vault
      secretKey: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    - envName: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
      secretName: vault
      secretKey: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    - envName: VAULT_AWSKMS_SEAL_KEY_ID
      secretName: vault
      secretKey: VAULT_AWSKMS_SEAL_KEY_ID
  ha:
    enabled: true
    config: |
      ui = true

      listener "tcp" {
        tls_disable = 1
        address = "[::]:8200"
        cluster_address = "[::]:8201"
      }
      seal "awskms" {
      }
  
      storage "raft" {
        path = "/vault/data"
      }
    raft:
      enabled: true
      setNodeId: true
      config: |
        ui = true
  
        listener "tcp" {
          tls_disable = 1
          address = "[::]:8200"
          cluster_address = "[::]:8201"
        }
        seal "awskms" {
        }
    
        storage "raft" {
          path = "/vault/data"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an answer explaining the same on [Hashicorp discussion](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/what-is-the-difference-between-ha-config-and-ha-raft-config-in-vault-helm-values-yaml/26724/4?u=matiasbertani).

I checked it out on the official vault helm chart and verified that :

- If you set `ha.raft.true: true` will use the config you specify at `ha.raft.config`.
- If `ha.raft.enable`: false will use the config at `ha.config`

[Here](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault-helm/blob/e2711a2002df36caef2efc3878806a2b9f29952d/templates/server-config-configmap.yaml#L29-L33) you can see the `if` statement, where the decision of which config use is made.